# How do you scrape HTML + HTTP POST responses?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

Does anyone know a way (free or paid tool, software library, etc) to scrape HTML and the HTTP responses? I've tried tools like Mozenda and Octoparse and they worked but only in getting the HTML.

If you open a site with chrome for example and open the developer tools, in the network tab you can see the traffic and the responses, I need to capture that same data but with a program.

I've tried replicating the post request and sending it with Postman and it worked, but I don't know how to automatize this (replicate the HTTP Headers sent would be the hard part, given that tokens expire)

Any type of help or tip would be very helpful thanks.

Comment: For this use-case you might want to choose Selenium, that should do the job. Puppeteer might also work, however my experience with it is limited, so don't pin me down on that.

Comment: You’ve tagged Scrapy. Isn’t that a possible answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after reading all the docs from Scrapy, Puppeteer and Selenium I can say it can be done with all 3, although the most straightforward way to do it would be with Puppeteer I believe.
We didn't scrape that site though it was too much work, we don't want to code a scraper from 0 is not that important for us.

Thanks, @Patrick Klein and @Gallaecio